# get groups of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql-table with entries which have a name and a heartbeat-datetime. Under perfect circumstances the heartbeat would occur every 10minutes:

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:10:00|
|A   |20180907 09:20:00|
|A   |20180907 09:30:00|
```

Now I have more persons:

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:10:00|
|B   |20180907 09:15:00|
|A   |20180907 09:20:00|
|B   |20180907 09:25:00|
|A   |20180907 09:30:00|
```

I can even have the same name from a second person with the same name. I can only distinguish them by their heartbeat.

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:10:00|
|A   |20180907 09:15:00| --> Second A
|A   |20180907 09:20:00|
|A   |20180907 09:25:00| --> Second A
|A   |20180907 09:30:00|
|A   |20180907 09:35:00| --> Second A
|A   |20180907 09:45:00| --> Second A
```

Sometimes, the heart can skip some beats (sometimes for hours)

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:10:00|
|A   |20180907 09:20:00|
|A   |20180907 16:46:00|
|A   |20180907 16:56:00|
|A   |20180907 17:06:00|
```

And last but not least: under normal circumstances, the heartbeat does not occur exactly every 10 minutes, but rather some seconds earlier (I have not seen a later heartbeat, but I wouldn't rule that out):

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:59:02|
|A   |20180907 10:08:50|
|A   |20180907 10:18:04|
|A   |20180907 10:27:50|
```

**What I want**: I want to get the Persons and their duration.
So let's say I have the following table:

```
|Name|Heartbeat        |
|A   |20180907 09:59:02|
|B   |20180907 10:05:50|
|A   |20180907 10:08:50|
|B   |20180907 10:15:20|
|A   |20180907 10:18:04|
|A   |20180907 10:27:50|
|B   |20180907 13:00:50|
|B   |20180907 13:03:42| --> second B
|B   |20180907 13:10:10|
|B   |20180907 13:12:56| --> second B
|C   |20180907 13:15:30|
|B   |20180907 13:19:46|
|C   |20180907 13:25:01|
|C   |20180907 13:34:53|
```

I want to get the following results:

```
|Name|Duration|StartTime|EndTime |
|A   |00:28:48|09:59:02 |10:27:50|
|B   |00:09:30|10:05:50 |10:15:20|
|B   |00:18:56|13:00:50 |13:19:46|
|B   |00:09:14|13:03:42 |13:12:56|
|C   |00:19:23|13:15:30 |13:34:53|
```

Is that even possible with T-SQL (I don't know the exact SQL Server version, but I suppose it is at least SQL Server 2014)?
I don't even have a starting point. So if someone would give me a hint into the right direction, I would be very gratefull.

I was thinking that cursors would be helpfull, but I do not know how to apply them in a helpfull manner.

Comment: find your version with `select @@version as 'sql server version'`

Comment: What if different persons with same name, starting `Heartbeat` same time? or first `A` starts with `20180907 09:10:00` and second person (also `A`) starts after 10 minute? how to understand who is who ?

Comment: unique identifier for every person, would be more helpful here

Comment: @OtoShavadze: I am not the master of the db. I can't change the schema, nor the way the entries are inserted. In your first example, it would be two persons.

Answer (score 0):

I am just suggesting the idea. Your requirement can not be satisfied with direct joins, reason being every time you need to compare the current entry with previous values. Steps you can perform here is

1. Step1: Group the table on Name and keep it in a Temp table
2. Step2: Run while loop for every group

Inside loop1

3. Step3: Run another loop for every entry (person name, which could be
   same for two)

Inside loop2

4. Step 4: Give a UniqueIdentifier for every person and do comparison
   with last heartbeat value for uniqueIdentifier with nearest match in
   range of 10 minutes. And save it in a table XYZ

e.g. start with

```
|B   |20180907 10:05:50|
```

Add below entry in XYZ

```
1D13EA00-58ED-4079-86AF-F103364D62CF |B   |20180907 10:05:50|
```

Next

```
|B   |20180907 10:15:20|
```

1. Group XYZ on UniqueIdentifier and find the last entry (Max time)
2. Find the time difference from the current entry.  Pick the one which
   comes in your range. Here you will have to rank them
3. Use the identifier of the Rank 1 and insert the current entry with the same
4. And if it is not in the range in any one of them, create a new
   identifier

Note: 
I have not covered the scenario where for many days no entry has come for a patient. In that case, you have to create a offset for every 10 mins.
e.g. You have these 2 entries only

```
|A   |20180907 09:59:02|
|A   |20180908 09:57:02|
```

In above case, you have to offset the time for |20180907 09:59:02| with 143 intervals of 10 mins. So, you will compare

```
|A   |20180908 09:49:02| //instead of |A   |20180907 09:59:02|
```

with

```
|A   |20180908 09:57:02|
```